# Is it possible to do GPGPU processing on Zero 2 w?

Tags: gpu, pi-zero-w-2

Is it officially supported or easily possible to do parallel general purpose computation on the GPU of the zero 2 w?
For instance with openCL support or something similar.
Much of the discussion is almost a decade old.